# Is there a way to find all branches created from a SVN branch?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subversion-edge

I'm trying to list all branches created from a Parent SVN branch to establish a graphical representation of a branch in Subversion. 
Are there any SVN command which can be used to achieve this? 
Or is there an approach to solve this?

Example:
 
Parent Branch: Branch1 
Child Branch: Branch2 and Branch3 (both branches created from Branch1).
GrandChildren Branch: Branch2.1, Branch3.1 etc., 
Given **Branch1**, I'm trying to list the child branches and Grand Children branches that were created from Parent Branch (Branch1) and Child Branches respectively.

Result:

Branch1-------------------Branch2-------Branch2.1 , Branch 2.2 ..
   |__________________Branch3-------Branch3.1, Branch3.2...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to solve. However I have limited my search to the children. Making a recursive script will let you find the grand children.

Because the repository I have to examine has a lot of branches and commits, `svn log` commands can be very slow. So, I separated the work in two steps:

1. Retrieve the commits logs that create the Children branches. I save them in a file, with a one line:

   ```
   parent='/branches/2014/new-components'
   svn log  https://svn.abc.org/branches/ -r1903:HEAD -v | ack -C2 "A.+\(from ${parent}:[0-9]+" >> kids.log
   ```

   The -r1903 is to limit the search to try speed up things a bit. I knew the parent branch was created at r1903, so no need to look before.

   I used `ack`, but `grep` would work the same.
2. I wrote a python 2.7 script to parse the `kids.log` file:

   ```
   from __future__ import print_function

   import re
   import subprocess

   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument("file", help="svn log file to parse")
   args = parser.parse_args()

   parent='/branches/2014/new-components'

   # Regexp to match the svn log command output
   #    1st match = revision number
   #    2nd match = author
   #    3rd match = date of creation
   #    4th match = branch path
   #    5th match = 1st line of commit message

   my_regexp = re.compile(r'r([0-9]+) \| (.+) \| ....-..-.. ..:..:.. \+.... \((.+)\) \| [0-9]+ lines?\n'
                          'Changed paths:\n'
                          ' *A (.+) \(from '+parent+':[0-9]+\)\n'
                          '\n'
                          '(.+)\n')

   with open(args.file, 'r') as f:
       matches = my_regexp.finditer(f.read())

   # print kids name
   bnames =  [m.group(4) for m in matches]
   print('\n'.join(bnames))
   ```

   **Tip**: I replace the last two lines with the following to gather all the matches:

   ```
   allinfo = [[m.group(i) for i in range(1,6)] for m in matches]
   ```

   then you can loop over `allinfo` and print out the information you need as you want.

Grand kids: To make a recursive script, steps 1 and 2 have to be converted into functions in one python script. And step 2 would call step 1 with the found kids name as argument. Objects may help keeping track of the entire family tree.